# Faster way to export large SQL Server CE database to XML file?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, sql-server-ce, compact-framework

What is a faster way to export large (25,000 rows) SQL Server CE database into XML file?

Here is what I currently use:

```
using (SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(strConnection))
{
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        cn.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(strCommand, cn))
    {
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "item");
        StreamWriter xmlDoc = new StreamWriter("Output.xml");
        ds.WriteXml(xmlDoc);
        xmlDoc.Close();
    }
}
```

It takes about 60 seconds inside emulator (Windows Mobile).

Also.. I am using Compact Framework 3.5 with SQL Server CE 3.5.

Current performance:
60 seconds entire code
~20 seconds for everything without `ds.WriteXml(xmlDoc);`, leaving ~40 seconds for `ds.WriteXml(xmlDoc);`.

Comment: You can try writing to the file directly instead of using `StreamWriter` try `ds.WriteXml("Output.xml")`

Comment: I tried, this doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Have you tried generating the result in  SQL server directly as as XML result? Have you compared the time for the da.Fill() vs ds.WriteXML() -- i.e., what is actually taking a long time.

Comment: ds.WriteXML() is the one that takes majority of time (40 seconds). Everything else with da.Fill() takes only 15-20 seconds.

Comment: If you build you own XmlWriter, you can use DataTable.WriteXML(yourwriter) -- YourWriter can be constructed using a StringBuilder as well as a number of different stream types. If StringBuilder() is still slow, it may be faster to generate the XML directly in the database. All of the WriteXml() variants ultimate call the same method to generate the output, just with different stream options (ok other options too)

Comment: Looks like you can save 15-20 seconds then by not using a DataSet, which is almost always a bad idea on a device.  It basically copies the data into RAM.  Just use a SqlCeResultSet and read it forward.

Comment: And where are you writing to?  If it's to Flash storage, that will be slower to write (flash has to erase an entire block, then write the data, and your data is almost certainly not full blocks, which could mean you're erasing a rewriting blocks lots of times, which ain't quick). You might save time by writing to a file in RAM, then copying that over to flash. Definitely worth a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the effort is worth it to you, the fastest method is probably to roll your own XML generation. The library implementation of XmlWriter() is loops within loops, with considerable generality.

Declare your own output stream specifying the buffer size to something reasonably large (but still sane). I have tested StringBuilder() before and append() to it millions of times with good performance. Other output options may not be as fast, but I would hope the StreamWriter gives good performance when buffersize if appropriate and it force you to build everything in memory.

Don't use da.Fill() -- replace with a SqlCeDataReader.

For each row. Generate the XML for a single row using logic that is coded as close as possible to the metal. I.e., Precalculate column index values, etc. instead of using column names within this loop, use hard-coded type conversions as needed. Don't loop through each column, put each column

Also, test by having the database generating XML output. Although I don't expect this to be the fastest, it is easy to try, and if it turns out to be fast you would never have discovered it without trying.

Comment: Thanks. I probably will try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is more lightweight:

```
    private void ExportDataTable(SqlCeCommand cmd, SqlCeConnection conn)
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        table.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        StreamWriter xmlDoc = new StreamWriter("Output.xml");
        table.WriteXml(xmlDoc);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't change much. I think the greatest time consumption is due to .WriteXml()